# How to get the Poincare map for a given system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

For the given system:
$$x'=-y+x(1-x^2-y^2),~y'=x+y(1-x^2-y^2),$$ four parts have been asked. 
(a)  Show that $p(t)=(\cos t , \sin t)^T$ is a periodic solution. (b) Rewrite interms of polar coordinates $(r,\theta).$ (c) Let $\Sigma$ be the ray $\theta=\theta_{0}$ through the origin. Show that the Poincare map $P:\Sigma \rightarrow \Sigma$ is given by
$$P(r_0)=\left[ 1+ \left( \frac{1}{r_0^2}-1 \right)e^{-4 \pi} \right]^{-1/2}$$ and that $P(1)=1.$ (d) Use the Poincare map $P$ to show that the periodic solution $p(t)$ is orbitally asymptotically stable.

Part (a) is pretty straight forward and part (b) gives 
$$r \cdot \left( \frac{1-r}{1+r} \right)^{1/2}=e^t~~~~~~\theta=t.$$

Can someone help me with parts (c) and (d) ? We haven't covered about Poincare maps in class. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Part (b) is incorrect. As soon as you get a correct (b), parts (c) and (d) follow immediately.

Comment: @Artem thank you. That's good to hear because I do know how to apply the polar. Seems not here though. I used $rr'=xx'+yy'$ and $r^2\theta'=xy'-yx'.$ Can you tell me how parts (c) and (d) follow ?

Comment: ...Assuming you know the definition of a Poincaré map. What is this definition, already?

Comment: @Did thank you. A Poincare map is the function mapping initial conditions to the solution of the DE at t = 2π, i.e. $p(x0) = ϕ(2π, x0),$
where $ϕ$ is the flow. The flow is the solution to the DE with the dependence on the initial condition.

Comment: Right -- and which part of this is difficult to compute?

Comment: @Did suppose I have the two results correct for $r$ and $\theta,$ what should be $\phi$ and the initial condition here ? And asymptotic stability has to do with real part of the eigen values being negative. Those are where I'm having a hard time.

Comment: Sorry but your only concern at the moment should be to solve (c). Its application to (d) (and asymptotic stability) will follow, but trying to get ahead of the music is not useful. Sooo... which problems to solve (c)?

Comment: alright, (c) would do...

Comment: @Did can you please explain how to do part (c) ? This is for the preparation of my preliminaries. I appreciate the help very much.

Comment: Note that $$\frac1{x(1-x^2)}=\frac1x+\frac12\frac1{1-x}-\frac12\frac1{1+x}=\left(\log |x|-\frac12\log|1-x|-\frac12\log|1+x|\right)'$$
hence $$\int\frac{dr}{r(1-r^2)}=\log |r|-\frac12\log|1-r|-\frac12\log|1+r|+C=\frac12\log\left|\frac{r^2}{1-r^2}\right|+C$$
thus $$\log\left|\frac{r(t)^2}{1-r(t)^2}\right|=2t+C$$ that is, for every $r_0\ne1$, $$\frac{r(t)^2}{1-r(t)^2}=\frac{r_0^2}{1-r_0^2}e^{2t}$$ in particular, $P(r_0)=r(2\pi)$ hence, for every $r_0\ne1$, $$\frac{P(r_0)^2}{1-P(r_0)^2}=\frac{r_0^2}{1-r_0^2}e^{4\pi}$$ and surely you can finish.

Comment: @Did appreciate it.

Comment: @Did, if I ask one question why we don't consider the solution of $\theta$ at all ?

Comment: We do, when we declare that the return map corresponds to the time $t=2\pi$.

Comment: @Did, so unless $\theta=\theta_{0}+t$ (in this eg.) this argument won't hold ?

Comment: @Did, I'm sorry for asking. But the definition of asymptotic stability has to do with the real parts of the eigenvalues of the linearized matrix being negative. Does that apply here or is there a analogue for Poincare maps ?

Comment: "the definition of asymptotic stability has to do with the real parts of the eigenvalues of the linearized matrix being negative" Not necessarily, one can also use the return map -- and here this is obviously the way you are supposed to go.

Comment: @Did, I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: @Did sorry to bother you again. So is it enough to say that, asymptotic stability follows because $r(2 \pi)=r(0)$ ?